# Integration using Euler $\int \frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }x\,dx$

Tags: integration, indefinite-integrals

I've just tried to use the Euler's formula for my integral, but I can't get the correct answer. So if anyone could help me I would really appreciate that.
This is my integral:
$$\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }{x}\,dx$$

P.S. The ingral must be solven using Euler's formula

This is where I've got stuck:
I started with this substitution:
$$\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} = -x + t$$
After derivating I get $dx= t^2 + 2x -1 /2(t+1)^2$.
After immpleneting it into my integral, I get to this point
$$\int\frac{(t^2+2t-1)(t^2+2t-1)}{(t^2+1)2(t+1)^2}\,dt$$ I don't have any idea what I should do next (thought to do another substitution but don't know what to substitute).

Comment: Well..I started with this substitution: $\sqrt{x^2+2x-1}$ = -x + t .
After derivating I get dx= t^2 + 2x -1 /2(t+1)^2
After immpleneting it into my integral I get to this point
$\int_{}^{}\frac{(t^2+2t-1)*(t^2+2t-1)}{(t^2+1)2(t+1)^2}$ and I don't have any idea what I should do next (thought to do another substitution but don't know what to substitute) @Moo

Comment: @DraganZrilić Since this quadratic has two distinct real roots, Euler's third substitution will probably offer the cleanest solution.

Comment: F**k Euler's substitution. It's a mess. :)

Answer (score 4):

After we get $$\int\frac{(t^2+2t-1)(t^2+2t-1)}{(t^2+1)2(t+1)^2}\,dt$$

We can try to transform it into alternate form. Just let

$$\frac{(t^2+2t-1)(t^2+2t-1)}{(t^2+1)2(t+1)^2} = a + \frac{b}{t+1} + \frac{ct+d}{(t+1)^2} + \frac{e}{t^2+1}$$

We can reduct the right to a common denominator.Then compare the coefficient.

Or we can substitute some t then we can get a lot of linear equation then solve them.(For convinience, we can substitute $t=0$,$t=1$,$t=2$,$t=3$,$t=4$,then get five equations.)

After solved, we get:
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{c}
a=\frac{1}{2}\\
b=1\\
c=0\\
d=1\\
e=-2
\end{array}
\right.$$

Then it's tranformed into (I do it by [WA](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=(x%5E2+%2B2x-1)%5E2%2F((x%5E2%2B1)2(x%2B1)%5E2)))

$$\int\left(\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{t+1} + \frac{1}{(t+1)^2} - \frac{2}{t^2+1}\right)dt$$

And now we can get the answer:

$$\frac{t}{2} + ln(t+1) - \frac{1}{t+1} - 2arctan(t)$$

It's hard and boring to caculate. But it works(●'◡'●)

Answer (score 1):

Before applying any substitutions, rewrite the integral as
\begin{align}
I=&\int\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }{x}\,dx\\
= &\ \sqrt{x^2+2x-1} +\int \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }dx
- \int \frac1{x\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }dx
\end{align}
Then, with the Euler substitution $\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} = t-x $
\begin{align}
&\int \frac1{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }dx=\int \frac1{1+t}dt =\ln|1+t|\\
&\int \frac1{x\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }dx=\int \frac2{1+t^2}dt = 2\tan^{-1}t\\
\end{align}
As a result
\begin{align}
I= \sqrt{x^2+2x-1} +\ln\left|1+x+ \sqrt{x^2+2x-1}\right|\\
- 2\tan^{-1}(x+ \sqrt{x^2+2x-1})\\
\end{align}

Comment: basic question i know, but what rule justifies decomposing the integral into those three parts?

Comment: @Hisham - decompose according to $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }{x}= \frac{x(x+1)+ x-1}{x\sqrt{x^2+2x-1} }$$

Answer (score 0):

Complete the square, then substitute. The subsequent partial fraction expansion is slightly simpler.

$$\begin{align*}
I&= \int \frac{\sqrt{(x+1)^2-2}}{x}\,dx \\
&= \int \frac{\sqrt{y^2-2}}{y-1}\,dy & y=x+1\\
&= \frac12 \int \frac{(z^2-2)^2}{(z^2+2z+2)z^2} \, dz & z=\sqrt{y^2-2}-y \\
&= \frac12 \int \left(1-\frac2z+\frac2{z^2} - \frac{4}{1+(z+1)^2}\right) \, dz
\end{align*}$$